# THE Magic Hexagon

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, permutations, hexagonal-grid

There are many magic squares, but there is just *one* non-trivial magic hexagon, as [Dr. James Grime explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkVSRwFWjy0), which is the following:

```
  18 17  3
 11  1  7 19
9  6  5  2 16
 14  8  4 12
  15 13 10
```

As it is done in [Hexagony](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony) this is easiest written as just one line, by just reading it row by row:

```
18 17 3 11 1 7 19 9 6 5 2 16 14 8 4 12 15 13 10
```

Of course there are twelve such list representations of this magic hexagon in total, if you count rotations and reflections. For instance a clockwise 1/6 rotation of the above hexagon would result in

```
9 11 18 14 6 1 17 15 8 5 7 3 13 4 2 19 10 12 16
```

@Okx asked to list the remaining variants. The remaining lists are:

```
15 14 9 13 8 6 11 10 4 5 1 18 12 2 7 17 16 19 3
3 17 18 19 7 1 11 16 2 5 6 9 12 4 8 14 10 13 15
18 11 9 17 1 6 14 3 7 5 8 15 19 2 4 13 16 12 10
9 14 15 11 6 8 13 18 1 5 4 10 17 7 2 12 3 19 16
```

plus all the mentioned lists reversed.

#### Challenge

Write a program that outputs the magic hexagon as a list. You can choose *any* of the 12 reflections/rotations of the hexagon.

Please add a few words on how your solution works.

Comment: Can this be done in hexagony? If so, I will put a bounty to reward that answer.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Anything *can* be done in Hexagony. It probably just won't be very interesting, because I doubt that you'll be able to save bytes over just printing one of the lists literally.

Answer (score 9):

## Octave, 24 bytes

```
'IKRNFAQOHEGCMDBSJLP'-64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f9f3dM7yM/NMdDfw9Xd2dfFKdjLJ0Bd18zk/38A)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“JɼQⱮȦ>Ȯ’Œ?
```

A niladic link returning the list of the given orientation reflected left-right.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//4oCcSsm8UeKxrsimPsiu4oCZxZI/////)**

#### How?

Just the kind of thing for which I made `Œ?`

```
“JɼQⱮȦ>Ȯ’Œ? - Niladic link: no arguments
“JɼQⱮȦ>Ȯ’   - base 250 number, 18473955480703453
         Œ? - shortest permutation of some set of natural numbers one through to some N
            -   inclusive which would lie at that index in a list of all permutations of
            -   those same natural numbers when sorted lexicographically.
            -
            -   - for example 7Œ?:
            -   - since 7 is greater than 3! and less than 4!+1, it references four items
            -   - the sorted order of permutations of 4 items is:
            -   - [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,3],[1,3,2,4],[1,3,4,2],[1,4,2,3],[1,4,3,2],[2,1,3,4], ...]
            -   - so 7Œ? yields [2,1,3,4]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

Both solutions generate the list `[3,17,18,19,7,1,11,16,2,5,6,9,12,4,8,14,10,13,15]`

```
19Lœ•δn2м×„Á•è
```

Generates a list of all (sorted) permutations of the range `[1...19]` and indexes into that list with a base 255 compressed base 10 number.

Or 15 bytes runnable online

```
•áRвºñ*$vn+•20в
```

Decompresses a base 255 string to a base 10 number and converts to a list of base 20 digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOiwwuDLmw6tOvwRi2VMk9HoICRwYVN//8DAA)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
.PC"A¡öò\x06\x11Ý"S19
```

(Control characters replaced with `\x06` and `\x11` for your viewing convenience.)

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.PC%22A%C2%A1%C3%B6%C3%B2%06%11%C3%9D%22S19&input=18473955480703453)

#### How it works

```
   "A¡öò\x06\x11Ý"      magic string
  C                     convert to number n using codepoints as base-256 digits
.P                S19   nth lexicographic permutation of [1, …, 19]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
18473955480703453œ?19
```

I really want to compress that big number, but I'm not sure how.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QwsTc2NLU1MTCwNzA2MTU@Ohke0PL//8B)

Comment: `18473955480703453` is 1 bytes shorter.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't a list of code page indices be shorter?

Comment: RE compression: It's the same number I used in mine. All you have to do is convert the number to bijective base 250 using `ḃ250` and index into the code page (which is now easier as there is a niladic atom for it, `ØJ`).

Comment: @NickClifford it would be 21 bytes too (19 indexes, an open quote and a close quote).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah, got it.

Answer (score 3):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
³←@uΙΒQH√y׀“L«─
```

Explanation:

```
...“     push the number 4121998669867569415662783
    L«   push 20
      ─  convert 4121998669867569415662783 from base 10 to a base 20 number aka base 10 array
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 24 bytes

```
⎕A⍳'RQCKAGSIFEBPNHDLOMJ'
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395A%u2373%27RQCKAGSIFEBPNHDLOMJ%27&run)

**How?**

```
⎕A                        ⍝ 'ABC...
   ⍳                       ⍝ indices of
    'RQCKAGSIFEBPNHDLOMJ'  ⍝ ← this vector
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 49 bytes

```
[...'ih3b17j9652ge84cfda'].map(n=>parseInt(n,26))
```

```js
console.log(
[...'ih3b17j9652ge84cfda'].map(n=>parseInt(n,26))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 37 bytes

```
36^^md1o3apsqxqkfhq6~IntegerDigits~20
```

Explanation (that may be already obvious as Mathematica is not a codegolf language, but according to the OP requirement):

```
36  : Number base
^^  : Input a number in arbitrary base. See BaseForm documentation
md1o3apsqxqkfhq6 : the number in base 36
~IntegerDigits~20 : convert to base 20 as list of digits
```

Output:

```
{18,17,3,11,1,7,19,9,6,5,2,16,14,8,4,12,15,13,10}
```

Comment: Note that [tag:kolmogorv-complexity] actually *is* about data compression.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 27 bytes

Inspired by rahnema1's solution.

```
`ikrnfaqogcmdbsjlp`¬®c -96
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YGlrcm5mYXFvlGdjbWRic2pscGCsrmMgLTk2&input=)